# Merging different partitions on Ubuntu 18.04LTS

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, partitioning, 18.04, gparted

I have just installed Ubuntu 18.04LTS. I installed it alongside Windows 10 but I want to use only Linux now. I had files in one of my Windows drives so I moved them to my home directory and now I want to format Windows partitions and merge them with Linux. More specifically:

[image]

What I want is to have just `swap` partition, `root` partition(maybe 400GB), an 300GB partition for my files and create a `home` partition with what is left(my hard drive is 1TB in size).

Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand the question. You clearly understand how to open GParted. Are you asking how to use GParted? Or are you asking something else? Pro Tip: Mucking with partitions is *always* dangerous, no matter how pretty the GUI. Always backup all your data before starting.

Comment: I have Windows 10 installed with Ubuntu 18.04LTS but now I want to only use Ubuntu. The problem is that in Windows I had Disk C and Disk R(each about 500GB which totals to 1TB which is my whole hdd). Now I want to resize the partition which contains Ubuntu, i.e. the root partition). In the end I want to have 3 partitions, which are: 1.`root` 2.`swap` 3.another partition for my file.

Comment: BTW I want to delete everything related to Windows including its boot entry. Thank you for your response.

Comment: Sure, your end state is clear enough. But you *already have the tool to do it* - GParted. Backup your data and use GParted to achieve what you want.

Comment: I am sorry but if I could do what I wanted I wouldn't bother you.